# Android: Alternate colours for list-view when using Base Adapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

Hi I have a list view and I want to give alternate colours for the rows ,but unable to achieve it, especially when I am using base adapter.

Below is my getView() method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View view = convertView;
    int sectionnum = 0;
    for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {
        Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);
        int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;

        // check if position inside this section 
        if(position == 0) return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);
        if(position < size) return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);


        // otherwise jump into next section
        position -= size;
        sectionnum++;
    }

    if(position % 2 == 0){

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  
           }else{

               view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);  
          }
    return view;


}
```

Comment: try to change the colour of the main parent of your row file.

Comment: What outcome are you getting using this code? Because it is working perfectly when I run it with my code.

Comment: @SayaleePote Not getting any of the colors mentioned blue or white

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View view = adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);
```

then set this view's background

and then return this view

You have to write above lines instead of

```
return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);
```

Comment: can you please eloborate

Comment: Please share your xml code and complete BaseAdapter code. Then I will be able to tell you exact code. Are you using ListView or RecyclerView?

Comment: can we move this conversation to chat so i can share my code

Comment: Yes we can have further conversation in chat.

Comment: how to get into chat.iam not getting any option

Comment: try this. setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)); Define blue color in color.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103707/discussion-between-hari86-and-nitesh-khatri).

Comment: your comment worked   ....     View view = adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);
then set this view's background
and then return this view
You have to write above lines instead of return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);

Comment: I have changed my answer. Kindly accept and up vote it so that others will get benefited.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below piece of code in your getView() of custom adapter to have listview with alternate colors

```
   ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_layoutan, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv3);


        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }




    if(position %2 == 0){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("your choice color"));
    }else{
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("your choice color"));
    }

    return convertView;
```

And declare a static inner class in your custom adapter like this

```
    static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv2;
}
```